# Right Callout Accessory method and implementation

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, annotations, mapkit

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to add a right callout accessory to a map annotation. everything i try doesn't seem to be getting anywhere, so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have tried this line of code but nothing different happens to the annotation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapview:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
MKAnnotationView *aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@""];
aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
aView.canShowCallout = YES;
aView.annotation = annotation;
return aView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried and exactly what errors or problems you get?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The method name is wrong.  It should be `mapView` with a capital `V`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender 
            viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

Objective-C is case-sensitive.

If the method still doesn't get called, then the other problem is that the map view's `delegate` is not set.  In code, set it to `self` or in Interface Builder attach the delegate to File's Owner.

Also make sure you set the `title` of the annotation before adding it otherwise the callout still won't show.

The above changes should fix the accessory button not appearing.

Some other unrelated suggestions...

In `viewForAnnotation`, you should support annotation view re-use by calling `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)sender viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"StandardPin";

    MKPinAnnotationView *aView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[sender 
                dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (aView == nil)
    {
        aView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                    reuseIdentifier:reuseId] autorelease];
        aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        aView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }

    aView.annotation = annotation;

    return aView;   
}
```

If your project uses ARC, remove the `autorelease`.

By the way, to respond to the accessory button press, implement the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
        calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"accessory button tapped for annotation %@", view.annotation);
}
```